# Bulk insert certain fields

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to import text files I receive but need to skip certain columns. Right now I use the below code to bulk insert into the database. I'd like to skip the lstnam, fstnam and midnam columns.

I know I could do the `ALTER TABLE Vendor DROP column` but I'd like to not have any name information imported at all. I've seen format file using bcp but have no idea how and haven't seen any good examples. Thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VENDOR]
(
        [ID_VENDOR] [INT] NULL,
        [VENDOR] [CHAR](20) NULL,
        [LSTNAM] [VARCHAR](60) NULL,
        [FSTNAM] [CHAR](35) NULL,
        [MIDNAM] [CHAR](1) NULL,
        [TITLCD] [CHAR](4) NULL,
        [FMTCD] [CHAR](1) NULL,
        [VENDTYP] [CHAR](2) NULL,
        [ADRLN1] [VARCHAR](55) NULL,
        [ADRLN2] [VARCHAR](55) NULL,
        [CITYCD] [CHAR](30) NULL,
        [STACOD] [CHAR](2) NULL,
        [ZIPCOD] [CHAR](10) NULL,
        [PAYVEN] [CHAR](15) NULL,
        [FEDTAX] [CHAR](16) NULL,
        [DBANAM] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
        [W9ONFL] [CHAR](1) NULL,
        [CN1NAM] [VARCHAR](20) NULL,
        [CN1PH1] [CHAR](3) NULL,
        [CN1PH2] [CHAR](3) NULL,
        [CN1PH3] [CHAR](4) NULL,
        [CN1PH4] [CHAR](4) NULL,
        [CN2NAME] [VARCHAR](20) NULL,
        [CN2PH1] [CHAR](3) NULL,
        [CN2PH2] [CHAR](3) NULL,
        [CN2PH3] [CHAR](4) NULL,
        [CN2PH4] [CHAR](4) NULL,
        [FEDFRM] [CHAR](2) NULL,
        [TAXTYP] [CHAR](2) NULL,
        [ALTNUM] [CHAR](15) NULL,
        [CONCOD] [CHAR](2) NULL,
        [PARCOD] [CHAR](2) NULL,
        [ASCCOD] [CHAR](4) NULL,
        [NTWROL] [CHAR](1) NULL,
        [PROVNO] [CHAR](15) NULL,
        [PRVCPY] [CHAR](2) NULL,
        [PRVORG] [CHAR](4) NULL,
        [COMPNO] [TINYINT] NULL,
        [CLMTYP] [CHAR](2) NULL,
        [LICCOD] [CHAR](2) NULL,
        [PPAREFFDAT] [INT] NULL,
        [PPAREXPDAT] [INT] NULL,
        [FILGRP] [CHAR](1) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

        BULK INSERT DBO.DW_VENDOR FROM 'c:\DataWarehouse\VENDOR.txt'
```

Comment: Cases like this I usually `BULK INSERT` into a staging table, scrub the data, then use `INSERT INTO` to move the data from the staging table to the final production table.

Comment: Thanks. It is a weird company that wants names and id's removed but on a db that is not on a network. I have been bulk inserting, creating a false id_num, exporting, putting on an external and then re-importing with bulk insert. was hoping there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Use a format file to skip columns 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-skip-a-data-field-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15
or Insert into table Select columns from OpenRowset https://blog.learningtree.com/how-use-openrowset-function-read-text-files/